# Primeiro e Último registro incluindo noturno

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou com o seguinte problema tenho os dados dessa forma:

```
codigo  data_hora        nome_ajudante
-------+----------------+--------------
1000004 2018-08-22 11:11 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-22 11:43 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-22 11:48 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-22 11:54 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-22 17:52 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 08:13 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 08:28 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 10:25 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 10:25 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 10:25 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 13:30 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-24 22:20 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-24 23:27 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-25 03:14 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-25 05:12 Carlos Eduardo
```

Precisaria pegar o primeiro e último horário do dia, porém também quando intervalo for noturno, dessa forma:

```
codigo  inicio              fim                 nome_ajudante 
-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------   
1000004 2018-08-22 11:11:00 2018-08-22 17:52:00 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 08:13:00 2018-08-23 13:30:00 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-24 22:20:00 2018-08-25 05:12:00 Carlos Eduardo
```

Utilizei essa query, porém os dias 24 e 25 se dividiram, devido ao agrupamento (GROUP BY).

```
SELECT 
    MAX(codigo) as codigo
    , MIN(data_hora) AS inicio
    , MAX(data_hora) AS fim
    , nome_ajudante 
FROM
    diarias_ajudantes.registro_terceiros 
GROUP BY nome_ajudante, EXTRACT(DAY FROM data_hora), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data_hora), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data_hora)
ORDER BY nome_ajudante, inicio ASC
```

Alguém sabe uma forma de conseguir o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 3):

A princípio, sua query está correta, ela pegou o menor e o maior `data_hora` de cada dia.

Mas se esse "noturno" que você diz seria considerar determinados horários como sendo o dia anterior, o que você pode fazer é, antes de agrupar, remover x horas. Por exemplo, se qualquer horário antes das 08:00 é considerado dia anterior, bastaria fazer assim (o problema seria se alguém entrar mais cedo no dia, como 07:50 né?):

```
SELECT 
    codigo as codigo
    , MIN(data_hora) AS inicio
    , MAX(data_hora) AS fim
    , MIN(data_hora - interval '8' hour ) AS inicioConsiderado
    , MAX(data_hora - interval '8' hour) AS fimConsiderado
    , nome_ajudante 
FROM
    test 
GROUP BY codigo, nome_ajudante, EXTRACT(DAY FROM data_hora - interval '8' hour), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data_hora - interval '8' hour), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data_hora - interval '8' hour)
ORDER BY nome_ajudante, inicio ASC
```

SQL Fiddle com meu teste: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d77e4/5

**PS:** Seus dados de exemplo tem duas vezes o mês ali em cima

#### Atualização 01/09/2018 - usando uma tabela de horários de entrada

Como o @thiagofred perguntou nos comentários, caso tenha uma tabela indicando os horários de entrada para cada funcionário, a query pode usá-la para calcular a primeira entrada de cada funcionário.

Ajustei o fiddle, que ficou aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ecb1b/1

Criei uma tabela com o código do funcionário e um inteiro indicando a hora de entrada do dia de cada funcionário. Com isso, bastou fazer o join na query e ajustar a cláusula de group by um pouco, ficando assim:

```
SELECT 
    test.codigo as codigo
    , MIN(test.data_hora) AS inicio
    , MAX(test.data_hora) AS fim
    , test.nome_ajudante 
FROM
    test
    join horarios on test.codigo=horarios.codigo
GROUP BY
    test.codigo,
    test.nome_ajudante,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM test.data_hora - interval '1h' * horarios.hora_entrada),
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM test.data_hora - interval '1h' * horarios.hora_entrada),
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM test.data_hora - interval '1h' * horarios.hora_entrada)
ORDER BY nome_ajudante, inicio ASC
```

No novo SQL Fiddle, é possível ver que o primeiro funcionário, que começa 8:00, possui uma linha a menos do outro, que com os mesmo horários começa 5:00.

Comment: Meu camarada, obrigado. Para a abordagem acima ficou correta, porém para horários menor que 08:00 não funcionou, como vc citou antes. Para amostra maior que tenho, troquei o **interval '8' hour** por 6 horas. Porém no universo que irei trabalhar, haverá horário 5h da manhã aproximadamente que serão início de jornada e horário de 7h da manhã que serão de fim de jornada. Se tivesse o dia qual se refere seria tranquilo, mas não terei essa informação.

Comment: Realmente aí dificulta. Você precisaria de um campo a mais na tabela, como `data_hora_saida`, ou uma flag indicando se é entrada ou saída. Outra saída ainda, meio gambiarra rs, seria gravar alguma informação a mais nos campos atuais, como adicionar um `'*'` no nome do ajudante indicando a saída, ou gravando código positivo para entrada e negativo para saída (`1000004` é entrada, `-1000004` indica saída do mesmo código).

Comment: Na verdade é que teremos um equipamento onde a pessoa fará interações, aí precisaria calcular o tempo entre a primeira e a ultima interação. Porém as pessoas não teriam horário fixo para tal interação. Logo, não tenho nenhuma opção de flag para isso.

Comment: Estes horários de início e fim, você tem eles (ou poderia ter) registrados para cada funcionário em algum lugar no BD? Se tiver, possivelmente poderia usar para subtrair esses valores do campo `data_hora`

Comment: Se eu tiver um turno pré-definido para cada funcionário em outra uma tabela, seria possível? Por exemplo, o turno normal desse funcionário seria 08:00 à 18:00. Atrasos e HE não serão tratados aqui. Ajudaria em algo esses dados? eu achei que seria possível algo, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Sim, fiz uma atualização na resposta para levar em conta esta outra tabela.

Comment: Entendi, mas se houver uma incidência 5 minutos antes, esse dado ficará como dia anterior.

Comment: Aí no caso, você poderia somar alguns minutos no group by também, porém o mesmo valeria para o horário de saída. Solução 100% acho que não terá mesmo, só se conseguisse incluir mais informações mesmo na tabela de tegistro, ou mesmo em uma outra que pudesse complementar.

Comment: Obrigado por dispor seu tempo, mas por enquanto minha situação está complicada. Queria ter mais informações para agilizar isso, mas o pior é que não tenho rs